# how to move to popToViewController: from tabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have my app is a TabBarController, and I have to take different actions depending on which tab is pressed, so, I delegate TabBarContoller, and I got it.

Now in case a tab which contents a NavigationController is pressed, depending on a database value, the view that should be shown is the first one or the last one, so in Tabs.m:

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
 NSArray *viewArrays = [(UINavigationController*)viewController viewControllers];

switch (tabBarController.selectedIndex) {

    case 3:
    {
        NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM login";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement = [[Database alloc] select:query];

        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
           [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToViewController:[viewArrays objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

The problem is objectAtIndex:1 doesn't exist right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can popView only if you have done pushView atleast once**. Print and see the objects inside **self.navigationController.viewControllers** using **NSLog** and if it contains some object then give your index appropriately(within the range), i am confused why you are doing **(UINavigationController*)viewController**, try this instead

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: the self.navigationController.viewControllers is empty: views (null)
, I think this is because of I'm on a tabBarController, not in the navigation controller, can it be?

Comment: its because since you havn't pushed any view so there arnt any view to  pop either